# Date type displaying with timezone on node-postgres module

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have stored input data in date format in postgres database, but when I am showing the date in browser it's showing date with timezone and converting it from utc. For example I have stored the date in `2020-07-16` format. But when i am showing the date it becomes `2020-07-15T18:00:00.000Z`. I have tried using `select mydate::DATE from table` to get only date but its still showing date with timezone. I am using node-postgres module in my node app. I suspect it's some configuration on node-postgres module? From their [doc](https://node-postgres.com/features/types):

> node-postgres converts DATE and TIMESTAMP columns into the local time
> of the node process set at process.env.TZ

Is their any way i can configure it to only parse date? If i query like this `SELECT TO_CHAR(mydate :: DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') from table` i get `2020-07-16` but thats lot of work just to get date

Comment: What data type is that column exactly? The "in the format" seems to indicate it's not a proper `date` column, but a `text` column

Comment: saved in date datatype column

Comment: Then Node.js messes with the display

Comment: i guess sth wrong with node postgres module

Answer (score 7):

You can make your own date and time type parser：

```js
const pg = require('pg');
pg.types.setTypeParser(1114, function(stringValue) {
  return stringValue;  //1114 for time without timezone type
});

pg.types.setTypeParser(1082, function(stringValue) {
  return stringValue;  //1082 for date type
});
```

The type id can be found in the file: node_modules/pg-types/lib/textParsers.js

Answer (score 4):

It is spelled out here:

https://node-postgres.com/features/types

date / timestamp / timestamptz

```
console.log(result.rows)
// {
// date_col: 2017-05-29T05:00:00.000Z,
// timestamp_col: 2017-05-29T23:18:13.263Z,
// timestamptz_col: 2017-05-29T23:18:13.263Z
// }

bmc=# select * from dates;
  date_col  |      timestamp_col      |      timestamptz_col
------------+-------------------------+----------------------------
 2017-05-29 | 2017-05-29 18:18:13.263 | 2017-05-29 18:18:13.263-05
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you query the date column, it's exactly that; a DATE.

- Not a string, so we need to convert it to string first
- Same as using `.toString()` with JavaScript.

Okay, back to your question:
Try:

```sql
SELECT DATE(date_added)::text AS date_added from [table_name]
```