# React MUI - DayJs displaying displaying date incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dayjs

So I am displaying a list of objects as MUI Cards on my react application. One of field on the object is of type `date` in postgres. For a sample card object, the value retrieved from DB is follows (seen in browser console from logs):

```
{
    "id": 43,
    "date": "2024-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "vehicle": "MH01EP6194",
    ...
}
```

I am displaying the date using `dayjs` format method:

```
dayjs(appt.date).format("DD-MMM-YY")
```

However the value is displayed as previous day i.e. 25-Mar-2024 instead of 26-Mar-2024. In database the value stored is `2024-03-26`. Any suggestion what I am doing wrong here?

[image: Card Snipped]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently node-postgres module adds server time zone in the `date` type column in postgres which was messing with my output. I changed the text parser for date type and it worked:
[Date type displaying with timezone on node-postgres module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923107/date-type-displaying-with-timezone-on-node-postgres-module)